# Where is the content of <?php echo $this->getChildHtml(’right’) ?>

Tags: magento, content-management-system, e-commerce

I’m trying to re-organise my right sidebar. In the template (2columns-right), it calls :

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?>`

Where can I find the content of this variable?

Answer (score 22):

A call to method `getChildHtml()` loads the HTML for the child block with the name which is passed to the method, so in this case we are looking for a child block named *right*.

To determine where to find this child block we need to know which block is calling this method.  I know that that particular call to the `getChildHtml()` method appears in the main page column template as *right* is one of the columns.  So have a look in the `page.xml` layout file and search for the template file inside which you found the method call, you will find something like this:

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
    <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
</reference>
```

Using the `<reference>` tag in a layout file allows you to alter the targeted block, and the `<action>` tag allows you to run a block method inside the block you are working with.  So this section of layout sets the template inside the *root* block.  From this we know that it is the *root* block calling the `getChildHtml()` method.

Next lets look at where the *root* block is defined in the layout, it's in the same `page.xml` layout file, and should be right near the top:

```
<block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
    ...
    <block type="core/text_list" name="right" as="right" translate="label">
        <label>Right Column</label>
    </block>
    ...
</block>
```

There is quite a lot defined in this block, but you can see that it is given the name *root* and defines quite a few child blocks.  One of these child blocks is named *right* and it is this block whose HTML is being output by the `getChildHtml()` method.  It is important to note the block type - `core/text_list`.  This is a special block type which means that when rendering out the HTML for this block using the `getChildHtml()` method, child blocks will also be rendered.  If the block type was `page/html` like with the root block, every child block added to the *right* block would need it's own `getChildHtml()` method call, using this block type, you only need a call to `getChildHtml('right')` and all child blocks will also be rendered.

As you can see the *right* block is defined here but it is empty.  This is because in exactly the same way as your have the tag referencing the root block (`<reference name="root">`) other layout files add child blocks to the *right* block by referencing the *right* block.

```
<reference name="right">
    ...
</reference>
```

So to finally answer your question (and hopefully inform a little along the way), you need to be looking in layout files other than `page.xml` for references to the *right* block, here you will find all of the child content output by the `getChildHtml()` method call.

You can alter what is added to the *right* block in your own module layout file, or `local.xml` layout file if you are not creating a module.  I briefly cover the `local.xml` layout file in my answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/adding-mini-cart-to-header-not-displaying/1500#1500) with example syntax to add new blocks and remove blocks added in other layout files.

Answer (score 1):

You will find  in your layout.xml file from where everything comes.It would have list blocks under which call .phtml files and data comes from there.I hope you understand what I am trying to convey.

Comment: layout.xml == catalog.xml? @chiragit007

Answer (score 0):

```
<reference name="right">  
    <block type="yourmodule/yourblock" name="yourblock" as="yourblock" />
 </reference>
```

You can add your custom blocks over there like this.

Comment: i have a problem with layout too, would you mind help me with this : `<layout version="1.0">
    <adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="paketid_booking/adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_view_booking" name="paketid_booking" template="paketid/booking.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_view>
</layout>`

my custom block not showing on shipment view? what am I missing? for complete question, take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39340112/adding-block-into-adminhtml-shipment-view