# How to show global message in home page header only

Tags: magento

I am trying to show global message on home page header only but not showing me.
I have copied the global message showing script from my home page but no luck....

any help would be highly appreciated..... 
Thanks in advance..

This is how worked for me...
added this into the header section of my `local.xml`

```
<block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
```

and the PHP call in `header.phtml`:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages'); ?>
```

Comment: You should post your code. Your description is not enough to understand.

Comment: @VipulHadiya Thanks for replay,                                         "<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>" I hope you have knowledge of this function, I just want to call this in header  how can I?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488885/understanding-getchildhtml-in-magento this will help you

Comment: @VipulHadiya Not related to my qestion

Comment: Yes it does... You are probably invoking `$this->getChildHtml()` without knowing how it works. The referenced block/html should be somewhere in the layout files as well... Read the post!

Comment: @RichardBernards heyyyy every time I post question you gave my answer thanks, I don't know but I wait for your answer....Thanks a lot dear... I wish i have knowledge like you in magento..... :-)

Comment: Have you read the post? And did you add the XML in the proper place? Copy-paste that code into your question and I'll be able to help you further.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I meant =)

Comment: @RichardBernards Thanks dear I will accept you as my teacher..you have to guide me. it's worked because of you otherwise I was not going to see that reference link....You said it's worked, without thinking I visited that page and go through it and it's worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the local.xml of your theme file search for the reference name "header" and paste this code

```
<block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
```

now you can use `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages'); ?>` in the header.phtml