# How to show product description at home page in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Am show all products to home page,its working fine.But its showing product price,image only now want to show product description also in home page how to show product description at home page?

```
<?php $_description = $_product->getProduct()->getDescription(); ?>
```

Not working the above code i put ,

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/temaplate/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

Comment: If you don't see an error message, you should check that your development environment is set-up properly. If you see an error message, add it to the question. Also when you have code that is "not working" you should write what you expected the code to do and what it did instead so that it becomes more clear what "not working" means to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you description of product

```
$_product->getData('short_description')
```

or

```
$_product->getShortDescription()
```

Comment: hi plz explain getChildHtml(); means what how it will work?

Comment: i suggest you to go through some posts, like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488885/understanding-getchildhtml-in-magento

Answer (score 1):

`$_product` is an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` so if you want the product description you should call `$_product->getDescription()` and not `$_product->getProduct()->getDescription()`