# getChildHtml did not get any value or content

Tags: php, magento

i just learned how to use Magento, Starting with make a new theme. i created page.xml, footer.phtml, header.phtml, 2columns-left.phtml, head.phtml. the problem is getChildHtml in the tempalte page did not get any content. anyone knows where i was wrong?

this is what i got

[image: rendered html]

**page.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
<default translate="label" module="page">
    <label>All Pages</label>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/2columns-left.phtml"/>
    <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/css.css</stylesheet></action>
    </block>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="after_body_start" as="after_body_start" translate="label">
            <label>Page Top</label>
        </block>

        <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
            <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch"/>
        </block>

        <label>Page Header</label>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
            <label>Navigation Bar</label>
            <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
        </block>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
        <label>Main Content Area</label>

            <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>

              <block type="core/text_list" name="left" as="left" translate="label">
                <label>Left Column</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
            <block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="right" as="right" translate="label">
                <label>Right Column</label>
            </block> 
        </block>
        <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml"></block>

</default>
```

**2columns-left.phtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div id="web-container">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
<div class="page">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        <div class="content">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
            <?php // This left_first block will display above the main content on smaller viewports ?>

            <div class="left"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>

            <div class="right">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_before') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_cookie_notice') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance ( •̀ω•́ )σ

Answer (score 2):

The `getChildHtml()` is a method that will load content from your `.phtml` file which is assigned  in your layout files `(.xml)`. Every thing is fine in your `page.xml` file except one thing, you need to add this,

```
<page_two_columns_right translate="label">
        <label>All Two-Column Layout Pages (Right Column)</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
            <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
            <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
            <action method="setLayoutCode"><name>two_columns_right</name></action>
        </reference>
    </page_two_columns_right>
```

`<reference>` tag in a layout file allows you to alter the targeted block, `<action>` tag allows you to run a block method inside the block you are working with. For more information refer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16032973/where-is-the-content-of-php-echo-this-getchildhtml-right)**.

And above mentioned block is copied from my magento 1.9. It may vary lower version. So please refer your magento(default) layout system, how they used that..

Comment: i tried to replace my page.xml with default page.xml, it works fine. but when compare them, i cant find what i was wrong =[[

Comment: Its working fine when using default one, so the problem is in your page.xml file only. Just compare it .

Comment: ah, found it. wrong at root block, i gave it a self close tag :/